# How to execute a loop in a dedent block?

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, ecmascript-6

Does anyone know how I can execute

```
req.body.documents.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element['_index']);
    console.log(element['_id']);
    console.log(element['_source'].uuid);
    console.log('--------------------');
});
```

inside a [dedent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dedent) block?

```
const description = dedent`

Date:     ${req.body.date}
Alert ID: ${req.body.alert_id}
    
LOG ENTRIES
===========

< Execute loop here >
`;
```

Or does this need to be solved with a template engine? If, any suggestions how to implement it?

Comment: What is a `dedent` block?

Comment: @jfriend00 I have now added a link to the npm in OP =) https://www.npmjs.com/package/dedent

Comment: But that's just a bunch of console logs; what would the point be? You could do the console logging outside of the string template. Are you trying to get the information you're currently logging *into* that string? In which case create a string and include it in the existing interpolation?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, you can interpolate even complex expressions inside [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
`LOG ENTRIES
===========

${
  req.body.documents.map(element => 
    [element._index, element._id, element._source.uuid].join('\n')
  ).join('--------------------\n')
}

`
```

Then `dedent` will just take care of extra indentation in the resulting string.

Comment: Would it even be possible to write text in front of each variable? E.g. `Index: <index value> \n`?

Comment: Sure, you can prepend each of those expressions in the array with the required string, for example `['Index ' + element._index, 'ID ' + element._id, ...]`. You can even use [nesting templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#nesting_templates) (ticks within ${ }), too.

Comment: Thanks so much! =)